# ngSwitch no reacciona ante una variable

Tags: html, angular

estoy liada con un pequeño problema que no se muy bien como solucionar.
He buscado mas preguntas parecidas en el foro pero no logro aclararme.
Tengo el siguiente problema:

```
    <div [ngSwitch]="lista" >
 <div *ngSwitchCase = "'accesorios'" >
<ion-list *ngFor="let item of accesorios"  (click)="irAcatmenu(item.url)"  icon-start>
  <ion-item >
    <button>
      <ion-icon [name]="item.icon + '-outline'" [ngStyle]="{'color': item.color}" item-start></ion-icon>
    </button> 
    <ion-label>{{ item.title }}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

```
<div *ngSwitchCase = "'servicios'" >
<ion-list *ngFor="let item of servicios"  (click)="irAcatmenu(item.url)"  icon-start>
  <ion-item >
    <button>
      <ion-icon [name]="item.icon + '-outline'" [ngStyle]="{'color': item.color}" item-start></ion-icon>
    </button> 
    <ion-label>{{ item.title }}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
 </div>
```

pues en [ngSwitch]="lista" lista quiero que sea una variable para poder cambiar el valor del ngSwichCase, esta variable lista la recibo por get de la siguiente manera:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServiciosService } from '../servicios.service';
import { ActivatedRoute,  Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LoadingController, NavController, } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
selector: 'app-form-producto1',
 templateUrl: './form-producto1.page.html',
 styleUrls: ['./form-producto1.page.scss'],

 })
 export class FormProducto1Page implements OnInit {

 accesorios = [];
 servicios = [];



  public lista: string = '';




     constructor(


public ActivatedRouted:ActivatedRoute,
public servicio: ServiciosService,
public route: ActivatedRoute,
public loading: LoadingController,
public navCtrl: NavController,
public router: Router ,


  ) { 



this.lista = this.route.snapshot.params.formproducto1Id;
  this.mascotas = [
    {
      'title': 'Perros',
      'icon': 'paw',
      'color': '#E63135',
      'url': '/form-producto1/Mascotas'
    },
    {
      'icon': 'paw',
      'color': '#0CA9EA',
      'url': '/form-producto1/Plantas'
    },
    {
      'title': 'Peces',
      'icon': 'fast-food',
      'color': '#F46529',
      'url': '/form-producto1/Alimentación'
    },
    {
      'title': 'Caballos',
      'icon': 'paw',
      'color': '#FFD439',
      'url': '/form-producto1/Ganadería'
    },
    {
      'title': 'Pájaros y Aves',
      'icon': 'paw',
      'color': '#CE6296',
      'url': '/form-producto1/Accesorios mascotas'
    },
    {
      'title': 'Conejos',
      'icon': 'people-circle',
      'color': '#3575AC',
      'url': '/form-producto1/Servicios'
    },
    {
      'title': 'Hurones',
      'icon': 'paw',
      'color': '#412159',
      'url': '/form-producto1/Adopciones'
    },
    {
      'title': 'Reptiles',
      'icon': 'paw',
      'color': '#412159',
      'url': '/form-producto1/Mascotas perdidas'
    },
   
  ]


  this.plantas = [
    {
      'title': 'Exterior',
      'icon': 'paw',
      'color': '#E63135',
      'url': '/form-producto1/Mascotas'
    },
    {
      'title': 'Interior',
      'icon': 'paw',
      'color': '#0CA9EA',
      'url': '/form-producto1/Plantas'
    },
    {
      'title': 'Arboles',
      'icon': 'fast-food',
      'color': '#F46529',
      'url': '/form-producto1/Alimentación'
    },
    {
      'title': 'Accesorios',
      'icon': 'paw',
      'color': '#FFD439',
      'url': '/form-producto1/Ganadería'
    },
    
   
  ]

 }  




irAcatmenu(url: string) {
 this.router.navigateByUrl(url);

 }
   ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

pero no se muestra los casos en pantalla solo funciona si en el código del .ts a lista le digo que : lista="servicios"; pero logicamente solo muestra ese caso, alguna sugerencia para que reflexione y vea que estoy haciendo mal, gracias.

Comment: si obtengo el valor correcto , por eso no entiendo que esta pasando

Comment: hola, es que no se que mas codigo mostrar la verdad

Answer (score -1):

En los `ngFor` debes cargar la variable lista que es quien contiene los datos:

```
*ngFor="let item of lista"
```

Comment: gracias por el aporte , pero no realmente cada array tiene su contenido la idea del ngSwitch es que muestre cada array según el valor de la variable lista, de esa manera no funciona .

Comment: una pregunta, si coloco lista="servicios"; me muestra el array de servicios mi pregunta seria puedo colocar entre los "" la variable  no se si me explico por ejemplo lista="variable"; esa variable la recibo con el ID .